# Spark Flatmap with Function on CSV RDD

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to apply a function within the flatMap function on a CSV RDD.

Here is the data input:

```
val rdd = spark.textFile("C:\\Users\\user\\Google Drive\\Besigheid\\Spark Project\\Spark Project - Project Property Value and Costs.csv")
```

I'm using the function called calculations:

```
def calculations(row:String){
      val data = row.split(",").map(_.trim)
      val number_of_years = 100
      val rate = 0.06
      data :+ "0"
}
```

I now want to run the function across the original data in the RDD and make changes to the subsequent output data. Unfortunately the line below does not compile.

```
rdd.flatMap(row => calculations(row)).saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\user\\Google Drive\\Besigheid\\Spark Project\\output")
```

Firstly I would like to make make changes to the input data before output. Should I return something with the function for this purpose?

Secondly, is it possible to append more lines to the original data set using this function?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: It means it is unable to compile. Sorry, I should have mentioned that it does not even get past the compiling stage.

Comment: Do you think it would be helpful for someone trying to answer this question to see the actual error message from the compiler? I do.

Answer (score 1):

You made a basic Scala syntax mistake:

```
def calculations(row:String){
```

This defines a function returning `Unit`. You need to return `TraversableOnce[String]` or a subclass. For example:

```
def calculations(row:String): Seq[String] = {
```

The compiler can automatically deduce this, just don't forget the `=`:

```
def calculations(row:String) = {
```